# Using HttpClient to make httpGet request

Tags: java, curl, apache-httpclient-4.x, http-get

I have the following cURL request:

```
curl -H "AuthToken: anything" http://localhost:9999/my_service/data?%24expand=total%2Callocated
```

I'd like to use Apache HttpClient to make this call in my application. My code is as follows:

```
HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(uri);
httpGet.setConfig(myConfig);
httpGet.addHeader("-H", "AuthToken: anything");
response = this.httpClient.execute(httpGet, httpClientContext);
```

However, this does not work - i get a response code 400.

What am i missing here? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

-H is an option for curl, not the actual HTTP header name your service is expecting.

I think you need to modify the header name here.

```
httpGet.addHeader("[Header name your service is expecting]", "AuthToken: anything");
```

And I guess it should look like this

```
httpGet.addHeader("AuthToken", "anything");
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure about -H parameter in

`httpGet.addHeader("-H", "AuthToken: anything");`

Looks like that -H is a just curl flag, so could  you  try just

`httpGet.addHeader("AuthToken", "anything");`

I don't know is this a root cause, but it looks like pretty strange.